# iOS iPhone/iPad Mail - rapid mass delete/delete all

Tags: ios, mail.app

How do you mass-delete emails in iOS Mail?

I don't know if this is documented anywhere, but just to bring it to current attention…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Late edit**
Not sure when this appeared but there is now [in 13.7] a simple 'Select All' button, like we always wanted. Follow that with Delete, accept the 'are you sure?' message & at last we have a simple solution. ;)

---

Scroll to the top or bottom of your list;
Tap edit, then swipe up or down the circular icons [the checkboxes] until you reach the other end.
It will quite rapidly auto-scroll once you reach the limit of the current view.
Tap Delete.
Gone.

100 unwanted emails, 3 seconds. Gone.

Discovered [by accident] on iOS 13.4.1